# What is "forward rotation" of a spacecraft?

Tags: attitude, spacecraft, isro, mars-orbiter-mission, rotation

According to [ISRO's Mars Orbiter Mission](https://www.facebook.com/isromom/posts/1402478439990096) (MOM):

> Forward rotation of the spacecraft
>   has been completed successfully.

What kind of maneuver is that and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a follow-up question in the comments to [this ISRO's announcement on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/isromom/posts/1402478439990096):

> **Rajesh B Nataraja**: Basic question? The forward rotation is to alter
>   the thrusters in the right direction for the sling shot?
>
> **ISRO's Mars Orbiter Mission**: You are absolutely right!

So this maneuver was about positioning the spacecraft in the direction for the last Trans-Mars injection burn, which, [according to ISRO on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1402500009987939&set=a.1384034005167873.1073741827.1384015488503058&type=1&theater), has been completed successfully:

[image]